# Canon ST-E2: Can I manually adjust the power of slave flashes using the camera menu?

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-flash

I know that the ST-E2 does not have the functionality to alter the power level of slave flashes in manual mode.  But can this be done via the camera's "External Speedlight control" menu.  I've Googled for about two hours or more and come up with nothing concrete.  Most of the posts concerning the ST-E2 were written before Canon included the in-camera Speedlight controls.  Specifically, I want to control the power of an off camera 430EX II set to manual using the "External Speedlight control" menu of my D5 MkIII with a ST-E2 attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. The ST-E2 is like a headless 550EX--it doesn't grok/speak the commands from the camera menu. You'd need a 580EXII or later hotshoe unit as master to have that kind of control.

If you don't have the cash to spring for the RT flash system or you want a small optical master, your best bet is probably to ditch the ST-E2, and get [a 90EX](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/cameras/flashes/speedlite-90ex) instead. It's contemporary with your 5DMkIII, understands and can relay the flash menu commands, while being an optical wireless eTTL commander.

However, TTL/HSS radio triggers, like the Yongnuo YN-622C, Phottix Odin, etc. etc. might be better yet, since you won't have to deal with the range and line of sight issues of optical slaving, and will give you full manual and even Groups mode control (where you can mix TTL/ratios, manual settings, and strobe groups together).

Comment: A set of Yongnuo YN-622C triggers is also an option that will give flash power (and zoom, and even mode) control over the 430EX II from the 5D Mark III's menu. With the YN-622C system the camera thinks the flash is hot shoe mounted and the flash thinks it is mounted on the camera's hot shoe. You can do anything via the radio triggers that you can do when the flash is directly on the hot shoe. You don't even enable "Wireless Control" in the camera's menu.

Comment: @MichaelClark, which is why I mentioned the YN-622C. [eyeroll]

Comment: I think we were both typing simultaneously and your edit  and my comment posted at roughly the same time. <double eye roll>

Comment: Edits made to an answer by the user that answered in the first 5 minutes after the answer is posted don't show up in the edit history.

Comment: A. k. a. "ninja'd!"

Comment: Inkiest: Thank you. And also to @MichaelClark for confirming.  Good to know that the ST-E2 isn't an option.  I did consider the 90EX, but discounted it as I understand it uses flash pulses rather than (near) IR to transmit information.  I'm taking portraits involving some vulnerable folk so the less flashes the better. The YN-622C seems the best option.  I have some question about these triggers, but I'll start a new post for those.  Thank you again.

Comment: @mooie, one great reference on the YN-622C is [Clive Bolton's TOYUG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMMzZFaDVlZ1VNTE0/view), _The Other YN-622C User Guide_; another is the POTN board's lighting forum, which I'm guessing [you already found](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1460694). :)

Comment: @inkiest: Thank you! The references are all very helpful.